# DDD: How do structure or resolve more complex behaviour in a domain entity?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Assume the classic Order/OrderLine scenario.

```
public class Order {
 ...
    public void AddOrderLine(OrderLine ol) {
        this.OrderLines.Add(ol);
        UpdateTaxes();
    }


    private void UpdateTaxes() {
        //Traverse the order lines
        //Collect the VAT amounts etc
        //Update totals 
        var newTaxes = Orderlines.SelectMany(ol => ol.GetTaxes());
        Taxes.Clear();
        Taxes.Add(newTaxes);

    }

}
```

Now, we figure that we need to handle taxes better, with different ways for customers in various countries etc, where some require VAT to be collected and others not.

In short, the tax rules will depend on the customer's location, items purchased etc. How would we do this? Should we put a lot of code into UpdateTaxes? Could we use tax calculator factory and reference it in UpdateTaxes?

```
private void UpdateTaxes() {
    var taxRules = TaxRulesFactory.Get(this);
    var taxes = taxRuleCalc.Apply(this);
    Taxes.Clear();
    Taxes.Add(taxes);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering your broader question regarding complex behaviour in ARs the preferred way to handle this would be to use double-dispatch.  Bear in mind that complex behaviour certainly *can* be included in the AR if that behaviour is cohesive.

However, for functionality that varies to the degree of tax or even discount calculation, where one would implement various strategies, you could opt for the double dispatch:

```
public class Order
{
    public void ApplyTax(ITaxService taxService)
    {
        _totalTax = taxService.Calculate(TotalCost());
    }

    public void ApplyDiscount(IDiscountService discountService)
    {
        _discount = discountService.GetDiscount(_orderLines.Count, TotalCost());
    }

    public Money TotalCost()
    {
        // return sum of Cost() of order lines
    } 
}
```

These services also should not be injected into the AR but rather passed into the relevant method.

Comment: AR, is that Active Record?

Edit: One more question: Someone must be responsible for calling the ApplyTax and ApplyDiscount after the order is updated. It could of course be the entity itself, but then IDiscountService and ITaxService must be added to the AddOrderLine method in order to do the correct tax calculations.

Comment: AR = Aggregate Root.  If you think about it an `Order` may be perfectly valid *without* calling `ApplyTax` even though it may be odd :) --- what *would* call it is the operation script, a.k.a. the application service.  The application service layer would have access to the various domain and other services to make the relevant sequential calls.

Comment: By far the most pragmatic and cleanest solution proposed.

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention about `OrderLine` tax.  You could, of course, structure the tax service to function at any level, even `OrderLine`, so you need not apply at the example level I proposed.  Tax probably *would* be at the `OrderLine` level anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

May be you could extract UpdateTaxes into a separate class which would be responsible for tax calculation against a particular order. And itself would chose an appropriate strategy (a separate strategy class) depending on customer, order, etc. I feel that tax calculation is a separate responsibility here.

Comment: So, for example, a domain service, which would fire upon an OrderUpdated event, which in turn will update taxes?

Comment: Yes, to avoid coupling. AR probably is an aggregate root in this context.

Answer (score 2):

You might also have a think about whether the concept of Tax and the concept of Orders need to be located within the same bounded context. It perhaps seems logical or at least implicit that when you're in the process of creating an Order you will want to know Tax due, but does this necessarily apply in your domain?

I'm not saying it does or it doesn't, by the way -- I'm simply saying think about it for your particular domain. Very often when the model seems awkward to represent it's because it mixes concerns that don't belong together.

Comment: I agree that this is something that needs to be considered.  Typically one would go from `Quote`, to `Order`, to `Invoice`, and who knows what else.  Tax typically would be applied from the very start, so `Quote`.  It may even need to be recalculated at each step as new laws may become applicable before a quote is accepted to become an order.  In e-commerce for instance, the shopping cart (quote) leads to an `Order` and then an `Invoice`.  So something like tax is a bit of a tricky business and may be managed (structures created) in a separate BC but consumed by others.