# How to inject dependencies into entities usign NHibernate 5.x integrated with Autofac 4.x?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, domain-driven-design, autofac

As the title says I'm trying to inject some dependencies (for example domain services) into entities using [NHibernate 5.2.6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NHibernate/) integrated with [Autofac 4.9.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac/).
Suppose we want inject `IPasswordHasher` doamin service into `UserAccount` entity:

**Example**

```
public class UserAccount 
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string EMail { get; set; }
    public virtual string HashedPassword { get; set; }

    private readonly IPasswordHasher _passwordHasher { get; set; }

    protected UserAccount() { }
    public UserAccount(IPasswordHasher passwordHasher)
    {
        _passwordHasher = passwordHasher;
    }

    public virtual void SetCredentials(
      string email, string plainTextPassword)
    {
        EMail = email;
        SetPassword(plainTextPassword);
    }

    public virtual void SetPassword(string plainTextPassword)
    {
        HashedPassword = _passwordHasher.HashPassword(
          EMail, plainTextPassword);
    }
}
```

I've already read [this article](http://chadly.net/2009/05/dependency-injection-with-nhibernate-and-autofac/) but unfortunately this article is very old-fashioned and vague to me.
In my last attempt I tried to set `NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.BytecodeProvide` using the [Autofac.Extras.NHibernate](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Extras.NHibernate/) NuGet package as follows:

**Using Autofac.Extras.NHibernate**

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

//Bootstrap the Autofac container
builder.RegisterType<PasswordHasher>().As<IPasswordHasher>();
builder.RegisterType<UserAccount>().AsSelf();
builder.RegisterType<StaticProxyFactoryFactory>().As<IProxyFactoryFactory>();
builder.RegisterType<DefaultCollectionTypeFactory>().As<ICollectionTypeFactory>();
builder.RegisterType<AutofacBytecodeProvider>().As<IBytecodeProvider>();
var container = builder.Build();

//Assign the BytecodeProvider to NHibernate
NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.BytecodeProvider = container.Resolve<IBytecodeProvider>();

Configuration nhConfig = new Configuration().Configure();
ConfigNHibernateAndAddMappings(nhConfig );

var SessionFactory = nhConfig.BuildSessionFactory();
var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession();

//entity._passwordHasher dependency is null when NHibernta warpped it with proxy
var entity= session.Query<UserAccount>().Where(x => x.EMail == "m@d.com").FirstOrDefault();
```

**The Problem** 
when there is no lazy loading, NHibernate doesn't warped queried entities with a proxy so in this case dependencies will be successfully injected. but when NHibernate warped the entity with a proxy, dependencies won't be injected and remain uninitialized ,any suggestion?

Comment: I suggest that you separate data and behavior. Put the code that requires the hasher in a different "service" or "function" or whatever.

Comment: @YacoubMassad tnx for your suggestion but we need inject behaviors to entities.

Answer (score 1):

You should not inject dependencies into your aggregate roots.

You *could* use [double dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33069570/ddd-how-do-structure-or-resolve-more-complex-behaviour-in-a-domain-entity/33094178#33094178) but nowadays I lean more toward passing in values to the domain objects from an application/integration *layer* (*concern*).

Instead of:

```
public virtual void SetCredentials(
  string email, string plainTextPassword)
{
    EMail = email;
    SetPassword(plainTextPassword);
}

public virtual void SetPassword(string plainTextPassword)
{
    HashedPassword = _passwordHasher.HashPassword(
      EMail, plainTextPassword);
}
```

I would opt for:

```
public virtual void SetCredentials(
  string email, byte[] passwordHash)
{
    EMail = email;
    Password = passwordHash;
}
```

Even better would be to have that as the constructor.

Your application service would have the hashing implementation injected using *traditional* dependency injection and your data access implementation would not need to concern itself with dependencies.

This is in line with what @Yacoub Massad is suggesting.  It is going to make your life somewhat simpler than even double dispatch.